# How to use lint-staged with jest --collectCoverageFrom

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, jestjs, lint-staged

I'm using [lint-staged](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) with [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html) testing framework to test only changed files from last commit as described in [this blog](https://benmccormick.org/2017/02/26/running-jest-tests-before-each-git-commit/).

My configuration is as below:

```
"src/**/*.{ts}": [
  "prettier --write",
  "tslint --fix --project .",
  "jest --bail --findRelatedTests",
  "git add"
]
```

I also want to generate coverage-report for only changed files. To do this, I have to put list of changed files in multiple places.

`jest --bail --findRelatedTests <spaceSeparatedListOfSourceFiles> --collectCoverageFrom=<glob>`

Using [lint-staged](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged), how can I limit both test and coverage-report only for changed files?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @chrisjlee, unfortunately, I did not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't know about `lint-staged`. I'll give it a try. I looked for this a while ago.

Have you tried?

`"jest --bail --coverage --findRelatedTests",`

[Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#findrelatedtests-spaceseparatedlistofsourcefiles) say that `findRelatedTests` *can be used together with --coverage to include a test coverage for the source files, no duplicate --collectCoverageFrom arguments needed.*

Should work but I haven't tried.

Comment: v22 did not have this. It seems to be added as of jest v23. I couldn't verify, since I didn't switch to v23, but according to jest docs, your answer should solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Should be `--coverage` not `---coverage`

Comment: Did it work for anyone? I am using `Jest 25.5.2` but it's still calculating coverage for all the files despite `--findRelatedTests` gives only 5 files.

Comment: @DebajitMajumder did you solve it?

Comment: I am using `--collectCoverageOnlyFrom $MODIFIED_FILES` where `$MODIFIED_FILES` is the list of files returned by `git diff  --name-only --diff-filter=AM $TARGETREMOTE/$TARGETBRANCH $SOURCEREMOTE/$SOURCEBRANCH -- 'src/*.js'`.

Answer (score 0):

it works correctly when you define the collectCoverageFrom parameter as follows

```
--collectCoverageFrom="<rootDir>/src/components/Home/index.js"
```

for multiple files you can define each as above

```
--collectCoverageFrom="<rootDir>/src/components/Home/index.js" --collectCoverageFrom="<rootDir>/src/components/Home/utils.js"
```

or you can define it as a glob

```
--collectCoverageFrom="<rootDir>/src/components/Home/*"
```